How can I apply custom physics in PageView when control with PageView controller?
I want to apply my custom physics to pageview if I am changing page by swiping by fingers it's working but if I am changeing page by pageviewcontroller.nextPage() or pageviewcontroller.previousPage() my custom physics not applying to pageview
custom physics:
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';

class CustomPageViewScrollPhysics extends ScrollPhysics {
  const CustomPageViewScrollPhysics({super.parent});

  @override
  CustomPageViewScrollPhysics applyTo(ScrollPhysics? ancestor) {
    return CustomPageViewScrollPhysics(parent: buildParent(ancestor)!);
  }

  @override
  SpringDescription get spring => const SpringDescription(
        mass: 10,
        stiffness: 200,
        damping: 1,
      );
}

Add physics to page view:
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    body: Container(
      width: double.infinity,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(gradient: kBackgroundGradient),
      child: SafeArea(
        child: PageView(
          physics: const CustomPageViewScrollPhysics(),
          controller:
              context.read<OnBoardingViewModelCubit>().pageViewController,
          // physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
          scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
          children: const [
            OnBoardingFirstPageView(),
            OnBoardingSecondPageView(),
            OnBoardingThirdPageView(),
            OnboardingFourthPageView(),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
}

And changeing page like this:
/// reverse onBoarding page
void showPreviousPage() {
  pageViewController
      .previousPage(
        duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 300),
        curve: Curves.linear,
      )
      .then(
        (value) => emit(state.copyWith(
          currentOnBoardingPage: pageViewController.page!.toInt(),
        )),
      );
}

/// Forward onBoarding page
void showNextPage() {
  pageViewController
      .nextPage(
        duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 300),
        curve: Curves.linear,
      )
      .then(
        (value) => emit(state.copyWith(
          currentOnBoardingPage: pageViewController.page!.toInt(),
        )),
      );
}


this is because it uses the given curve, in your case:  curve: Curves.linear

@pskink but curves is required for both methods

yes, i know, and thats why nextPage / prevPage use it and not PageView.physics - the docs for physics say: "How the page view should respond to user input.
For example, determines how the page view continues to animate after the user stops dragging the page view." - it does not mention that it is used for those two methods - try to use Cureves.ease for example if you dont like linear movement
